# dlopen fails on android with NDK 10d

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

i'm trying to open a dll using System.loadLibrary

```
 System.loadLibrary("myLib");
```

the lib is found and loaded but it's crashing with an UnsatisfiedLinkError

E/AndroidRuntime( 5557): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "pow" referenced by "libmyLib.so"...

i thought that gcc was implicitly linking to libc and libm...

- i tried to link it manually, without much success.
- i tried to link to gnustl_shared.

Am i missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Post you `Android.mk` and `Application.mk`

Comment: Without being sure if it applies in this particular case, it is worth mentioning that there have been a number of regression issues of this sort where bionic switched between implementing things as a macro and as a library function.  If you build with a toolchain that considers it to be a library function, and run on a device which assumes it should be a macro, you will get this sort of failure.   You might try comparing the headers of the new NDK and an older version.

Comment: Another possibility is that you accidentally included headers from your development system rather than Android NDK headers.

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to link it manually ? Are you trying to use `double pow(double, double)` from cmath/math.h ? You aren't getting any warning during compilation ?

Normally, adding this in your *Android.mk*:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lm
```

should properly link your sources to the NDK's libm.so